# How to get data from variable and database with spesific value to count it into chart on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, variables, charts

i want to make chart that count summary of data from user_id with a few value, example i want to count how much user_id with value 1 or 2? the goal is i want to visualize it to chart. Before this, I made a chart but it count how much data from user_id, peserta_id and kecamatan_id. This is the code i use on chart view:

```
 @php
    $val = array($report->peserta_id,$report->user_id,$report->kecamatan_id);
    $data = array_sum($val);
@endphp
...
@if(isset($jenispopuler->peserta_id))
    @php($peserta_id = $jenispopuler->peserta_id)
@else
    @php($peserta_id = 0)
@endif
@if(isset($jenispopuler->user_id))
    @php($user_id = $jenispopuler->user_id)
@else
    @php($user_id = 0)
@endif
@if(isset($jenispopuler->kecamatan_id))
    @php($kecamatan_id = $jenispopuler->kecamatan_id)
@else
    @php($kecamatan_id = 0)
@endif
... 
series: [{
                    name: 'Jumlah',
                    data: [{{$peserta_id}}, {{$user_id}}, {{$kecamatan_id}}]

                }]
```

and this is the controller i use:

```
public function index()
{
    $report = DB::table('transaksis')->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))
                ->selectRaw("SUM(user_id) AS user_id, SUM(peserta_id) AS peserta_id, SUM(kecamatan_id) AS kecamatan_id")
                ->first();

    $jenis = Jenis::select('id','jenis')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(4)->get();

    $jenispopuler = DB::table('transaksis')
                    ->selectRaw('( SELECT COUNT(jenis_id) FROM transaksis WHERE jenis_id=1  ) AS user_id, ( SELECT COUNT(jenis_id) FROM transaksis WHERE jenis_id=2  ) AS peserta_id, ( SELECT COUNT(jenis_id) FROM transaksis WHERE jenis_id=3  ) AS kecamatan_id')
                    ->groupBy('jenis_id')
                    ->where(\DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(transaksis.created_at, "%Y")'), '=', date('Y'))
                    ->first();

    return view('home', compact('report','jenispopuler','jenis'));
}
```

and now I am confuse about to get data or count the value from the same column table. I will put my database image and the red mark on there is what i mean by the data/value that i want to count (maybe my explanation not clear hehe), Thanks in advance!

[image: database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$jenispopuler = DB::table('transaksis')->where('user_id','1')->count();
```